# Should distinct non-parallel line in $R^3$ have intersection point? True or False?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

True or False Question:
Any two distinct non-parallel lines in $R^3$ must have an intersection point.

I think it is not true, but not sure how to prove that. If you know the solution, can you please help me out to find it?

Comment: It’s not true; cf. [skew lines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines)

Comment: The title need a correction. It should be 'non-parallel' instead of 'parallel'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two non parallel straight lines in 3-space can either intersect or else, be skew.

When they intersect in a common plane, they have a common normal PZ to the plane at intersection point.

When skew like PY and black line through Q their common normal PQZ includes minimum distance between intersection points PQ.

If the straight lines are represented by vectors $(\bar X,\bar Y)$, then their common normal has direction of cross vector product $(\bar X \,\times \bar Y)$.

[image: Skew Lines]